# how to get chart object inside a point event function in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How have I to modify the following example to get the point value in the first series even when clicking on a point in the second series? It suffices to me to get the `chart` object but I don't know how to do (inside point `mouseOut` function `this` refers to `point` object and not to `chart` object).

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            // here I want the y value of the point in the
                            // first series even in this function 
                            // is invoked for the point in the second series
                            alert('value: ' + this.y);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0]
            },{
            data: [135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

[JSfiddle page](http://jsfiddle.net/bgontg3z/1/)

Comment: Try `this.series.chart`.

Comment: Well done, thank you.

Comment: Do you mean something like: http://jsfiddle.net/4dpx3aaL/3/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.point.events.click):

> The this keyword refers to the [Point](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point) object.

[`Point`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point) in turn has [`series`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series) property that holds [`chart`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series--chart):

```
series: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
        events: {
            click: function() {
                var chart = this.series.chart;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is right, obviously, but I'm unable to find the wanted information inside the linked docs page.